# Get Cookies from background script to content script when opened a page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have created a WebExtension that required user access token and makes a http request, So whenever user logs in my website I am saving the access token in cookies. This will then be retrieve by my extension to perform certain operations.

my background js

```
var pnumber,JWTtoken
function getCookiesForTab(uri) {
   var gettingAllCookies = browser.cookies.getAll({url: uri});
   gettingAllCookies.then((cookies) => {
   var JWTtoken
   if (cookies.length > 0) { 

    for (let cookie of cookies) {
      if (cookie.name == 'JWTtoken'){
        this.JWTtoken = cookie.value
      }
    }else{
      console.log("No cookies Found");
    }
  });
}
getCookiesForTab("http://localhost:5000/")
chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 
{JWTtoken:this.JWTtoken})
})
```

and my content script

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(req,send,res){
       if(req.JWTtoken){
        console.log(req.JWTtoken);
        // this.JWTtoken = req.JWTtoken
        DoSomeWork(req.JWTtoken)
      }
   })
```

The problem is I want to get cookies right when user opens the page but it is sedding message and fetching only when i click on the  extension. 
I have added background.js script to my popup.html. 
Is there anyway to do it

Comment: When you add background.js to your popup it becomes a standard popup script. The [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) runs in a hidden background page and must be declared in manifest.json.

Comment: Can I get Cookies from the background script? I tried doing that but failed

Comment: "failed" is vague. Debug your code and describe what happens in detail. See [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)